# Clojure date variables to pass into a database query

Tags: date, clojure, automation, date-format

I want to use two variables, dateFrom and dateTo. the script in which they exist will be run automatically by a job scheduler. I want the two variables to be updated automatically so that they can be passed to a DB query and are always pulling back the data from the previous day.

Therefore, if today is the 13th of September, dateFrom should contain bthe 11th of september and dateTo should contain the 12th of september.

Every time the script is run, the variables should be automatically updated.
The format for the date should be YYYYMMDD

Does anyone know if this can be done in Clojure?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know how to do that in Java?

Comment: I cant say I do... I'm guessing your going to say use the java library for this in the clojure?

Comment: @Chiron sorry i do know how to do this in Java. Date date = new Date(),  use simple date format to get the format i want and store it as a variable. Parse the date string to an int and -1 for the previous day giving dateFrom and dateTo. Now for the clojure variant...

Comment: @Blue42: All that converting between different date formats isn't necessary if you use the Calendar.add method instead.

Comment: What I'm talking about is this https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`clj-time`](https://github.com/seancorfield/clj-time) for this:

```
(use '[clj-time.core :only [days minus today]]
     '[clj-time.coerce :only [to-sql-date]])

(let [start (-> (today) (minus (days 2)) to-sql-date)
      end   (-> (today) (minus (days 1)) to-sql-date)]
  [start end])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example session from the Clojure REPL with the required operations:

```
user=> (import java.util.Date)
java.util.Date
user=> (def now (Date.))
#'user/now
user=> (import java.util.Calendar)
java.util.Calendar
user=> (def cal (Calendar/getInstance))
#'user/cal
user=> (.setTime cal now)
nil
user=> (.add cal Calendar/DATE -2)
nil
user=> (def dateFrom (.getTime cal))
#'user/dateFrom
user=> (.setTime cal now)
nil
user=> (.add cal Calendar/DATE -1)
nil
user=> (def dateTo (.getTime cal))
#'user/dateTo
user=> (import java.text.SimpleDateFormat)
java.text.SimpleDateFormat
user=> (def sdf (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyyMMdd"))
#'user/sdf
user=> (.format sdf dateFrom)
"20130912"
user=> (.format sdf dateTo)
"20130913"
```